# "Error reading POM" when selecting a archetype in Maven setup

Tags: maven, maven-3

I downloaded maven 3.0.3, set-up my environment variables as instructed and verified with `mvn --version` that everything looks ok. So far so good

So, time to RTFM.. about 1 minute into the manual, weirdness occurs.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
  -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app \
  -DartifactId=my-app
```

It asked me to select a archetype from this long list, I took the quickstart one 135.

However, this doesn't work.. it spits out the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.1:generate
>   (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error reading POM -> [Help 1]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up-to-date documentation: the [free book by Sonatype](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/). I learned some stuff from there even after using Maven for over 3 years.

Comment: while helpful, this doesn't answer the question at all